# Controller beanPostProcessor spring - not singleton?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have a custom beanPostProcessor that is supposed to do some logic with spring controllers.

I found out that it behaves funny. When I sysout controller bean in my post processor it says:

```
 ...controller.MassUploadController@743479ce
```

but when I call `sysout(this)` from controller request itself it is a different instance:

```
...controller.MassUploadController@58469848
```

So any changes I perform to controller instance in beanPostProcessor are not really reflected in runtime since it is a different instance. How is that possible? It states everywhere that spring controllers are singletons! 
My controllers are defined in spring with `@Controller` and in xml I use **componentScan** on **controller.** java package

Comment: Post some configuration and your post processor. Make sure you aren't scanning for components twice (which is what appears to happen).

Comment: You were totally right! I had component scan 2x in my XML configuration... Thank you!